# Making a Pangram function in Python but having a problem with the letter T

Tags: python

first time posting, new to programming. Issue I'm having is when I run my Pangram function, and turn the input string into a set list, the list still has multiple 't' but none of the other letters. when I input "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" when my code turns this to an organized list to match the alphabet, there are 2 t's. As you can see i'm using print to see what everything is doing

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

above is what my input string converts to and there are 2 t's but all other multiple letters are gone. I also tried making the upper T a lower T manually, and also making other random letter upper and it has no problem with other letters.

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    
    str1 = str1.replace(' ','')
    str1 = list(set(str1))
    str1 = [letter.lower() for letter in str1]
    str1.sort()
    print(str1)
    alphabet = list(set(alphabet))
    alphabet.sort()
    print(alphabet)
    
    if str1 == alphabet:
        return 'Is Pangram!'
    else:
        return 'Is not Pangram!'
```

Comment: Lowercase the letters *before* you make them into a set…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting your string to lowercase after collecting a set, you should make it lowercase before the set

```
str1 = list(set(str1.lower()))
```

Comment: Thank you! never realized it was important, assumed I could lowercase at any point, as we can see.

Answer (score 0):

You are lowercasing the characters **after** building the `set`, so `T` and `t` are considered different.

Instead, lowercase before building the `set`:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    str1 = str1.replace(' ','')
    str1 = [letter.lower() for letter in str1]
    str1 = list(set(str1))
    str1.sort()
    print(str1)
```

Or in a much shorter way:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    str1 = sorted(set(str1.replace(' ','').lower()))
```

Comment: Thanks! the shorter way looks cleaner, haven't seen that 'sorted()' function before now. as you can see I'm doing basic stuff at the moment.